# GraalVM/Polyglot: how to get SourceLocation programmatically

Tags: graalvm

Is there a way to get the current source location (SourceSection) from java?

e.g. a js script executed via context.eval() calls a java method, the java method logs the current js script name+line

PolyglotException has a getSourceLocation() that provide this information. also stack traces from polyglot seems to contains information about the source location e.g. at  :program(Unnamed:2:23-53)

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you need this? There may be better ways depending on your actual use case.

Comment: at the moment it's mostly for debug purposes. when a java call is called from the javascript, I want to know from which source/line of javascript it was called. basically i want to Log messages with the js-source:line information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you asked this a long time ago, but I have just seen it for the first time.

Here is a way to get to the current location easily:

```java
static StackFrame getCurrentLocation() {
    PolyglotException e = Context.getCurrent().asValue(new RuntimeException()).as(PolyglotException.class);
    for (StackFrame frame: e.getPolyglotStackTrace()) {
        if (frame.isGuestFrame()) {
            return frame;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here is a full runnable example:

```java
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Context context = Context.newBuilder().allowHostAccess(HostAccess.ALL).build()) {
            context.getBindings("js").putMember("test", new Test());
            
            Source source = Source.newBuilder("js", "test.callback()", "mysource.js").buildLiteral();
            context.eval(source);
        }
    }
    
    public void callback() {
        System.out.println(getCurrentLocation());
    }
    
    
    static StackFrame getCurrentLocation() {
        PolyglotException e = Context.getCurrent().asValue(new RuntimeException()).as(PolyglotException.class);
        for (StackFrame frame: e.getPolyglotStackTrace()) {
            if (frame.isGuestFrame()) {
                return frame;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
<js> :program(mysource.js:1:0-14)
```

Comment: Is there also a way to extract the function name? like Truffle.getRuntime().getCallerFrame().getCallNode().getRootNode().getQualifiedName();

Comment: frame.getRootName() should do the same thing here.
we will likely add a way to differentiate simple and qualified name in the future here as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hacky solution: You could pass the `new Error().stack` as an argument to your java function to get a stack trace. Given

```
public class A {
    public A() {}
    public void foo(String x) {
        System.out.println("MY ARGUMENT IS: " + x);
    }
}
```

you can

```
$GRAALVM_HOME/bin/js --jvm --vm.cp=.
> function bar() { var x = new (Java.type("A"))(); x.foo(new Error().stack) }
> bar()
MY ARGUMENT IS: Error
    at bar (<shell>:6:1:56)
    at <shell>:7:1:1
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution, but I'm still not sure if it is good or bad one. but at the moment it's the only one that seems to work.

Basically, I need to add a bunch of --add-opens to java args:

```
--add-opens org.graalvm.truffle/com.oracle.truffle.api=ALL-UNNAMED 
--add-opens org.graalvm.truffle/com.oracle.truffle.api.frame=ALL-UNNAMED 
--add-opens org.graalvm.truffle/com.oracle.truffle.api.nodes=ALL-UNNAMED 
--add-opens org.graalvm.truffle/com.oracle.truffle.api.source=ALL-UNNAMED
```

And then using the Truffle runtime I'm able to get the caller frame and SourceSelection

```
Truffle.getRuntime().getCallerFrame().getCallNode().getEncapsulatingSourceSection()
```